# Formula to find n where nth term >= x

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, arithmetic-progressions

How many months does it take for $d$ to become at least $x$ where for $m$ months $a$
is added to $d$ $(d = a + d)$ but at every $m$+1 month $b$ is added to $d$ $(d = b + d)$ then repeats again while $d < x$? 

For example: $d$ = 2, $a$ = 5, $m$ = 4, $b$ = 3, $x$ = 51 
\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l |}
        \hline
    Month(n) & d & Increment\ amount & Final\ amount \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & a & 2 + 5 = 7 \\ \hline
    2 & 7 & a & 7 + 5 = 12 \\ \hline
    3 & 12 & a & 12 + 5 = 17 \\ \hline
    4 & 17 & a & 17 + 5 = 22 \\ \hline
    5(m+1) & 22 & b & 22 + 3 = 25 \\ \hline
    6 & 25 & a & 25 + 5 = 30 \\ \hline
    7 & 30 & a & 30 + 5 = 35 \\ \hline
    8 & 35 & a & 35 + 5 = 40 \\ \hline
    9 & 40 & a & 40 + 5 = 45 \\ \hline
    10(m+1) & 45 & b & 45 + 3 = 48 \\ \hline
    11 & 48 & a & 48 + 5 = 53 \\ \hline
\end{array}
From the above table, it can be seen that $d$ $\geq$ $x$ at month 11. So
it therefore took 11 months for $d$ to be more than or equal to $x$.

I was able to deduce that the above is a special case of arithmetic progression where the $n^{th}$ term
can be found using a tweaked version of the arithmetic progression formula:
   $$ \alpha_n =  \alpha_1 + ( n - 1)a - (floor(n \div m) \times ( a- b)) $$ 
 where:
    $\alpha_n = value\ of\ n^{th}\ term $ 
    $\alpha_1 =\ first\ term $ 
    $a =\ normal\ increment\ amount $ 
    $b =\ increment\ amount\ to\ add\ at\ m\ +\ 1 $ 

 
Example: $d$ = 2, $a$ = 5, $m$ = 4, $b$ = 3, $x$ = 51, $n = 11$, $\alpha_1 = d+a $

$\alpha_n =  \alpha_1 + ( n - 1)a - (floor(n \div m) \times ( a- b))$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $(d+a)$ + $(11-1)5$ - $(floor(11 \div 4) \times ( 5 - 3))$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $(2 + 5)$ + $(11-1)5$ - $(floor(11 \div 4) \times ( 5 - 3))$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $(7)$ + $(10)5$ - $(2 \times ( 2))$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $(7)$ + $50$ - $4$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $57$ - $4$ 
$\alpha_{11}$ = $53$ 
I was thinking the following equation can be used to find $n$ where $n$ can be transposed. 
   $$ \alpha_n =  \alpha_1 + ( n - 1)a - (floor(n \div m) \times ( a- b)) $$
   $$ \alpha_n \geq x $$
   $$ \alpha_1 + ( n - 1)a - (floor(n \div m) \times ( a- b)) \geq x$$

Answer (score 0):

Each block of five months adds $4a+b$.  You need to add $x-d$, so the number of full five month blocks needed is $k=\lfloor \frac {x-d}{4a+b}\rfloor$  Now you are at $d+k(4a+b)$ so you need $x-d-k(4a+b)$.  You get increments of $a$, so you need $\lceil \frac {x-d-k(4a+b)}a\rceil$ more months.  We get to ignore the fact that the last month only gives us $b$ because we covered that in the first step.  If you had a month before the last that gave $b$ we would need to be more careful.